# XCode Storyboard Localization Duplicate Strings Merge?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, localization, builder

I am currently working on an iOS app and localizing it into multiple languages but have faced an annoying (not breaking) issue.

When i would add a new localization for my storyboard xcode will automatically populate the strings, which is very nice. The issue i am having is that i have multiple interfaces which both have a back button. The text on these is of course the same and their translations are as well.
The question i was wondering about, is it possible, without using strings.localizable, to somehow merge multiple object translations into one?

This is how it would currently look:

```
"Pnu-Ec-HAj.normalTitle" = "Back";
"Rtx-fT-rdc.normalTitle" = "Back";
```

But it would be way easier if there was a syntax such as

`"Pnu-Ec-HAj.normalTitle", "Rtx-fT-rdc.normalTitle" = "Back";`
 (this syntax is not correct obviously)

I have looked around quite a while but have not found any answers to this question yet.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend referencing every text in your storyboard in code, and setting the text on viewDidLoad like, e.g.:

`buyButton.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"SHOP_BUY_BUTTON_TEXT",@"Button for buying product in detail view");`

It's loads of work if you have huge storyboards, but in the end you have a clean `Localizable.strings` with concise keys and comments, providing necessary context for your translators.

I prefix the key with the section of the app, so for example `SHOP_***`, `USER_SETTINGS_***`, etc.

In addition, we use a service like [OneSky](http://www.oneskyapp.com) to organize our translations online and update them from the cloud (not affiliated with them, and it's not without its teething problems either).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `.strings` files are [key-value files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) and, by nature, there must be a key (that is composed by the nib ID of the element followed by the property) and the associated string value.

As Apple describes in the precedent link:

> The standard strings file format consists of one or more key-value pairs along with optional comments. The key and value in a given pair are strings of text enclosed in double quotation marks and separated by an equal sign.

then, your idea is not supported by the `.strings` files.

The only way to support that feature is by using the `NSLocalizedString` in code.